# Automate PowerPoint with VB.net. Are there any limitations?

Tags: vb.net, vba, powerpoint

I am from vba and want to use vb.net to create PowerPoint Slides. I read the msdn documents about automate office but couldnt find an answer to my question: Are there any limitations? Or can i use the full power that i have with vba when creating powerpoint documents?

Comment: yes, you can use all features you know from VBA. Moreover, there are some more possibilities when you use VSTO to make add-ins, templates, and so on... However you will need to use VB.NET instead of VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, using the ActiveX creator in .Net to create "Powerpoint.Application" gives you a  reference to a COM object which is exactly the same as .Application within Powerpoint itself.

So you can do anything in .Net that you can do with .Application inside Powerpoint VBA.

(Note that one of the biggest restrictions with Powerpoint is that you can only have one instance of the executable running on a machine.)

Comment: if i doesnt need ppt embedded in vb.net can i use interop directly without ActiveX creator?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by using VB.NET/C# you have at your disposal all the power of the .NET platform itself.

Working with lists and collections in .NET is WAY easier than with their counterparts in VBA.

Also, with the PowerPoint.Application object you can control virtually anything that powerpoint is doable in powerpoint (the same applies to word, visio, excel, project, etc.).

The only limitation I can see in using .Net for office automation is that you do not have the same "tight" integration with the document. But if you create a addin with VSTO, this problem vanishes.

Comment: could you please explain what you mean with ""tight" integration with the document"?

Comment: Deployment is, to my knowledge, way easier in VBA than it is in .NET/vsto.

In vba you have easy and direct access to the ThisPresentation, ThisDocument, ActiveSheet objects. Your VBA Code is in the context of 'that' document in which the code is in. 

If you are going to use .NET, you can have the same access, but it will mean messing with microsoft.office.excel.application.globals.activeworkbook.(....)